# Using web-scraping techniques to extract one piece of information from google maps

Tags: javascript, r, google-maps, web-scraping, rvest

This is in reference to [my earlier question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271900/grabbing-a-places-description-from-google-places-api-in-r) Someone suggested to use rvest to extract the red circled piece of information imaged below. However, it seems that the page, when downloaded, is in Javascript format. As seen in the earlier question, this piece of information is not available in the API for unknown reasons. Even the rep I spoke to wasn't sure why it wasn't exposed to the endpoint.What would be the best way to write this to preference script speed? Any help is greatly appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]

EDIT: I've tried PhantomJS to strip out the Javascript and just get the HTML. However, this did not work.

Comment: did the rep you spoke to say it might be exposed to the API in the future? I agree, it seems like it should be there already...

Comment: Also, Google often have rules against scraping their pages, so worth checking their terms of service too.

Comment: @SymbolixAU No plans for future exposure. She even recommended using "alternative methods", but that was ambiguous. Import.io is able to get the information needed, but their service level is a tad expensive.

Comment: The feature request to add the detailed category in place details exists in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822953. However, there is no ETA.